# Why am I getting 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occured in DLL'

Tags: c#

I was able to upload the file successfully on my destination path, however I'm getting this error and I don't know why.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using R.One.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using R.One.All.Common.Base;
using R.One.All.Common.Base.Components;
using R.One.All.Common.Base.DAO;
using R.One.All.Common.BusinessObjects;
using R.WebServices.Facilities;

namespace Facilities.UploadSRLogo
{
    public partial class UploadSRLogo : SaveFileUploadBasePage
    {
        private string destinationFilePath = string.Empty;
        private int maxFileSize = 2048000;
        private bool isUpload = true;
        private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get the Posted File
        }

        protected override void SetOutputFilePath()
        {
            try
            {
                FileRepository fr = new FileRepository(base.Env, base.DBServer);
                string repositoryPath = fr.getRepositoryPath(base.user.PMCID.ToString(), "");
                string internalPath = @"\R\Facilities\";
                string outputFilePath = string.Format("{0}{1}", repositoryPath, internalPath);

                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(outputFilePath);
                if (!file.Directory.Exists)
                {
                    file.Directory.Create();
                }

                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(outputFilePath);
                string tempFileName = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                file = new FileInfo(this.ImportFile.Value);
                destinationFilePath = outputFilePath + tempFileName + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.Extension);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(destinationFilePath) == true)
                {
                    System.IO.File.SetAttributes(destinationFilePath, System.IO.FileAttributes.Normal);
                }
                this.OutputFilePath = destinationFilePath;
                if (this.ImportFile.PostedFile.ContentLength > maxFileSize)
                {
                    uploadResponse.ConfirmAction = false;
                    FileResult.Value = "ERR_FILE_SIZE";
                }
                else if (this.ImportFile.PostedFile.ContentLength <= 0)
                {
                    uploadResponse.ConfirmAction = false;
                    FileResult.Value = "ERR_FILE_EMPTY";
                }
                else
                    uploadResponse.ConfirmAction = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                uploadResponse.ConfirmAction = false;
                uploadResponse.ReasonFailed = "System error: " + ex.Message + " : " + ex.StackTrace;
                uploadResponse.TechnicalReasonFailed = "Error in UploadPreferredItems - SetOutputFilePath";
            }

        }


        protected override void PostHandleInputFile()
        {
            if (!uploadResponse.ConfirmAction) return;

            try
            {
                SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(destinationFilePath);

                if (isUpload)
                {
                    base.OutputObjects.Add("UploadResponse", uploadResponse);
                }
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                uploadResponse.ConfirmAction = false;
                uploadResponse.ReasonFailed = "System error: " + ex.Message + " : " + ex.StackTrace;
                uploadResponse.TechnicalReasonFailed = "Error in UploadSRLogo - PostHandleInputFile";
            }
        }


        #region Private Methods

        private SRLogoPhoto SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(string destinationFilePath)
        {
            return SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(destinationFilePath);
        }

        #endregion Private Methods
    }
}
```

I am getting the error on this part:

```
private SRLogoPhoto SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(string destinationFilePath)
{   <------on this part is the error
   return SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(destinationFilePath);
}
```

Help pls. SaveSRLogoPhotoSite method is on another asmx.cs file which was included on my 'Using R.WebServices.Facilities' above.

For reference, I will also paste the SaveSRLogoPhotoSite method below:

```
#region SaveSRLogoPhotoSite
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true, Description = "Save sr logo photo in site db")]
[SoapHeader("Authentication")]
[R.One.All.Common.Base.Attributes.ProtectionLevel(true, 10, 20, "8vwsr", RightsBehavior = "or")]
[R.One.All.Common.Base.Attributes.SoapAuthExtension(Priority = 1)]
public SRLogoPhoto SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(string filePath)
{
    DataSet ds = null;
    Hashtable param = new Hashtable();
    SRLogoPhoto srlp = new SRLogoPhoto();

    try
    {

        System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

        Byte[] b = new Byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
        fs.Close();
        SqlParameter P = new SqlParameter("@Picture", SqlDbType.VarBinary, b.Length, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, null, DataRowVersion.Current, b);

        string sqlStr = "UPDATE SRSiteLogo SET srImage = @Picture ";

        param.Add("Picture", P);

        dbHelper.Entity = OneSiteDB.DBEntity.Site;
        ds = dbHelper.GetDataSet(sqlStr, param);


        #region SQL Code
        string sqlStr2 = "select srImage from SRSiteLogo";
        #endregion

        int PictureCol = 0;
        SqlDataReader reader = dbHelper.ExecuteSqlDataReader(sqlStr2);
        reader.Read();
        Byte[] b2 = new Byte[(reader.GetBytes(PictureCol, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
        reader.GetBytes(PictureCol, 0, b2, 0, b2.Length);
        reader.Close();

        string webservicepath = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
        string destfilepath = webservicepath.Replace("\\WebServices\\Facilities", "\\221\\Facilities\\300\\Setup\\srlogo\\images\\S" + base.SiteID + "Logo.jpg");

        System.IO.FileStream fs2 = new System.IO.FileStream(destfilepath, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
        fs2.Write(b2, 0, b2.Length);
        fs2.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        srlp.Error = "SaveSRLogoPhotoSite() web method failed on call to dbHelper.GetDataSet - " + ex.Message;
    }

    return srlp;
}

#endregion
```

Comment: You return the result of the method you are currently in? Its an endless loop, it looks like you wish to call the method with the same name in another class but then you need to specify this `return someClass.SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(destinationFilePath);`

Comment: I just want the method to run only once when the SaveSRLogoPhotoSite is successful. How do i do that?

Comment: Right now, you are not "running" it at all. Your `private SRLogoPhoto SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(string destinationFilePath) { return SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(destinationFilePath); }` calls itself, not the method you want. And it does so infinitely.

Comment: oh ok.. i get it. i have a new problem now, how do I call that method from other asmx.cs file? sorry, i'm new to this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this snippet

```
private SRLogoPhoto SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(string destinationFilePath)
{   <------on this part is the error
   return SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(destinationFilePath);
}
```

the method `SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(string)` is calling itself. Thus, if you call that method once, it will keep on calling itself until you run out of stack, ie. get a [StackOverflowException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you have an implementation in another assembly or namespace that you meant to call, you will have to qualify it with a full name

```
private SRLogoPhoto SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(string destinationFilePath)
{   
   return SomeAssembly.SomeNamespace.SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(destinationFilePath);
}
```

If you have copied this piece of code from another place (you say that "SaveSRLogoPhotoSite method is on another asmx.cs", but I'm not entirely sure what that means), you will have to figure out what `SaveSRLogoPhotoSite` refers to in that context.

Comment: This should be a comment since it doesn't provide a solution

Comment: thank you for your answers! I had to instantiate the class where that method is in and then that is what I called. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
private SRLogoPhoto SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(string destinationFilePath)
{   <------on this part is the error
   return SaveSRLogoPhotoSite(destinationFilePath);
}
```

Oh, the irony, we are on stackoverflow.com...

This code makes no sense. It calls itself without any other operation (or break condition). This will lead into an "endless" recursion. Of course, until the stack is full.

Comment: sorry, im new to this. I just want to call that function once and break it.. how do i do that..

Comment: @ifallelsefailthenstackoverflow You don't need to call that function at all - it's not doing anything.  It's just giving you back what you already have - an `SRLogoPhoto` - which you have in the form of `srlp`, which you need to build a model for, by the looks of this.  Once you have something like `public class SRLogoPhoto() { public byte[] yourPhoto; }`, then you can do `srlp.yourPhoto = b2;`  You don't use that function you're trying to use.  When you want to get it, you just use `byte[] yourPhoto = SRLogoPhoto.yourPhoto;`

Answer (score 1):

is it a recursive call? Step debug in it. (Or the constructor dont work, because initialization crashes.)

=> implement your SaveSRLogoPhotoSite function

Comment: This should be a comment